# Linux download manager with automation feature?

Tags: linux, debian, bittorrent, download-manager, transmission

I am looking for a debian download manager which can watch folders on a remote FTP site and download new files to my computer locally. This is a one way operation and not a sync, I simply need to get files from my transmission (torrent) folder on remote FTP downloaded locally automatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out [NcFTP Client](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/) (is available in Debian repository)

Also look at [The NcFTP Overview at IBM developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-ncftp_flex/index.html) (note the Recursive Transfers section).

Actually it can't run in daemon mode. To make periodical downloads you have to write a tiny bash script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    ncftpget -R -u username -p password ftp.example.com /local/torrents /remote/torrents
    sleep 60
done
```

And then run it in *Screen* or *dtach* session to prevent terminating upon closing of a terminal window. In fact you can use any console FTP client you like with such a script to do automated periodic downloads like this.

Comment: see also [GNU Screen article at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) and [dtach manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dtach)

Comment: Any other options ?

Comment: Consider using [curlftpfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) ([there is a debian package](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ftpfs)). It allows you to mount a remote FTP directory to a local one and copy files from a FTP resource to a local directory just as you copy regular files (using `cp` for example). Anyway you have to write a simple script that will be executed periodically (even if you decide to use a ftp client (there is a bunch of them) - it is likely you have to run it from a script with passing certain parameters like login and password).